# Why git asks to commit every file after switching to master branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm new to git and got confused. I was developing in my feature branch, but need to make new feature. So i was planning to switch to master to fetch changes, and than create new branch based on latest master.

However after switching to master i have 2700 changes to commit. When i use fetch it says its up to date with origin. GitHub Desktop lists stashed changes and shows error "Unable to restore stash when changes are present in your branch". I never used stash.

When i try to switch back to feature branch i get error: "You local changes would be overwritten by checkout."

Could someone explain me what happened and how to manage this?

Btw I use some private company repository server, maybe it causes problem.

Comment: Most likely file permissions. If you run `git diff` what are the changes?

Comment: It's on Windows. All files has no content changes.

Comment: Did you use `git switch`? Because `git switch`, in comparison to the more standard `git checkout`, copies all the changes to the new branch...

Comment: @kaffarell: for this particular usage there should be no difference between `git switch` and `git checkout`. @And1: are there *non-content* changes? In particular do you get `old mode 100644 new mode 100755` or `old mode 100755 new mode 100644`? (Note: I recommend reading through [ask] and [mre] as well.)

Comment: Yes, i checked 30-50 files and they are all non content changes. I've created new feature branch and commited all changes to it. Still don't understand, but problem kind of solved (hopefuly merge will be easy).